# ImportError: cannot import name 'Index' from 'DeepImageSearch'

Tags: python

I installed DeepImageSearch and tried to run the code to find such similarity images (like here: https://www.kaggle.com/code/nulldata/deep-image-search-for-finding-similar-images)

```
from DeepImageSearch import Index,LoadData,Search_Setup
image_list = LoadData.from_folder(['myfolder'])
image_list[:5]
Index(image_list).Start()
SearchImage().get_similar_images(image_path=image_list[0], number_of_images=5)
```

but I got the following error:
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wct2F.jpg)

I tried reinstalling DeepImageSearch, but it still didn't work.

Comment: I'm guessing that the tutorial you linked is now outdated and doesn't work for the latest version. Check out the docs for DeepImageSearch: https://github.com/TechyNilesh/DeepImageSearch/blob/main/Documents/Document.md

Comment: Also, please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: @SuperStormer you are right. Tutorial was old. From your link working correctly. Thanks